# Error installing sails in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I am getting the follwewing error while installing sails

```
> sails@0.11.0 preinstall E:\jb\npmtest\node_modules\sails
> node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sails"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;

npm ERR! sails@0.11.0 preinstall: `node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sails@0.11.0 preinstall script 'node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sails package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sails
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\jb\npmtest\npm-debug.log
```

I tried to insatll sails 0.10 I am getting this error

```
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
\


> ws@0.4.32 install E:\jb\npmtest\node_modules\sails\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sails@0.10"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;

npm ERR! ws@0.4.32 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.32 install script '(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have tried to fix this error by trying `npm cache clear` as suggested by this link https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2751. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you give us more output from the console? That is not actually an error

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by running command `npm install -g sails --ignore-scripts`